# Installing a GUI on Open-WRT

Tags: wds, openwrt, home-networking

I have a Siemens SX763 router on which I installed Open-WRT. It did not come with a GUI (or so I think) so I googled around and only options I found were to install a GUI over the Internet. However I'd use that router as a WDS so I only have Wireless access.

Is there a way I could download the GUI and install it over USB? Or can I use wireless to connect to the Internet and install from that?

Are there any guides or directions?

Comment: Trying to upload firmware over a wireless connection is a nearly guaranteed way of bricking the firmware on the rounter.  **You need to use a wired connection**  You also don't seem sure if you have a GUI or not, you want to confirm that, because OpenWRT does have one.

Comment: No, OpenWRT is definitely on the router I just can't access GUI. I only have CLI. I uploaded the firmawre using wired connection because I'm aware that I shouldn't use wireless when doing that!

Comment: When you go to the intranet address of the router in a browser what do you get?

Comment: Well when I do ipconfig I get the following result:
http://imgur.com/6EH2wnH

So when I go to 192.168.1.150 I get an error saying that the webpage isn't available. However when I go to PuTTY and use SSH to access that IP address I get the following:

http://imgur.com/nZxtAIJ

Comment: I don't know what firmware you installed exactly OpenWRT clearly has different configurations that enable/disable features based on that choice.  OpenWRT should have a GUI if it doesn't then load a different configuration of OpenWRT that does.

Comment: Do you have any links or guides on how to do that?